# Will angular 6 cli build Angular app created with Angular/cli@1.7.4

Tags: angular-cli, angular6

I have to work in a couple projects at the same time.  One is angular6 another was created from angular/cli@1.7.4.  Is the angular6 cli backwards compat with 1.7.4?  Or could should I just install v6 globally and have 1.7.4 installed as devDependancey in my 1.7.4 app?

Not sure what will work here and afraid to dork up my dev box.

Comment: You can have a global version greater than your local version, your app wont crash, i have cli v6 installed as my global and a project created with cli v1.5.4 , i only see a warning message when i serve or run. But i don't have any other issue

Comment: Thanks @DanielTorresLaserna.  Running v6 globally and 1.7.4 locally seems to be working fine.  I was just over thinking this one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a global version greater than your local version and your app wont crash, i have `cli v6` installed as my global and a project created with `cli v1.5.4` , i only see a **warning message** when i `serve` or `run`. But i don't have any other issue